# How do I present a valid opinion that I don't have references for

Tags: discussion, support, references

I have a question about my Health Stack Exchange post: [Safe alternatives to painkillers/nsaid?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/8726/safe-alternatives-to-painkillers-nsaid/8735#8735)

So I answer a question, there is something I say that I think is helpful but don't have the references for it so what is the best way to convey this across without references.   I mean some questions are very detailed and if I was to provide an indepth answer with references then I might as well be writing a journal paper.

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: With respect, it looks like this is not the only answer of yours lacking proper referencing. For example, you answered a question of mine about HIV cure and provided a lot of your thoughts without giving references to support them: http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/8695/could-we-cure-hiv-through-transplantation-of-white-blood-cells-resistant-to-hiv. Idem for your answer regarding seizure prevention: http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/746/what-steps-can-i-take-to-prevent-a-seizure-from-occurring. Maybe you should also consider adding references to them?

Comment: One more point: there are several answers on this site (also to more complex questions) which provide very accurate informations (Health SE is about facts and evidence, not opinion, maybe this is confusing you...) and some good references to support them. Maybe you should have a look at those answers? I am new on HealthSE and they provided me some good examples on how to write a "good" answer. I also had a look at some "tips" to search for medical literature on the internet, this might maybe also help you. Cheers, Felipe

Comment: Thank you, I understand your point. I think as a new user I thought of this site as a general discussion forum. I don't use forums that much really.